# How to use StreamBuilder and asynchronous code in authentication?

Tags: flutter, firebase-authentication, stream-builder

I'm creating an App in Flutter that uses a Provider with Firebase Auth as authentication.

I've created a wrapper to handle the authentication states:

```
  StreamBuilder<GoogleUser?> authenticationWrapper(BuildContext context) {
    // Firebase Auth instance
    final googleAuth = Provider.of<FirebaseAuthApi>(context);
    return StreamBuilder<GoogleUser?>(
      stream: googleAuth.user,
      builder: (_, AsyncSnapshot<GoogleUser?> snapshot) {
        // Google auth stream active
        if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.active) {
          final GoogleUser? user = snapshot.data;
          // User logged in
          if (user != null) {
            return const HomeScreen();
          }
          // No user logged in
          else {
            return const LoginScreen();
          }
        }
        // Google auth stream inactive
        else {
          return const LoadingScreen();
        }
      }
    );
  }
```

Repare that the `LoadingScreen()` Widget is returned during the Stream inactivity.

Now, I want to add a asynchronous check if it's the first login of the user, before returning the `HomeScreen()`, without re-building my `LoadingScreen()`, because in it there is a `CircularProgressIndicator` Widget.

All aproaches I've been tried didn't worked at all, because I added a `FutureBuilder` before returning the `HomeScreen()`, and it forced me to re-build the `LoadingScreen()`.

Thanks for suggestions on how to not need to re-build my `LoadingScreen()` or return values (and not Widget) from a `StreamBuilder`.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not so sure but I think this is your answer. Everything remains same just add this in `main.dart`:

```dart
home: StreamBuilder(
    stream: FirebaseAuth.instance.authStateChanges(),
    builder: (ctx, userSnapShot) {
        if (userSnapShot.hasData) {
            return HomeScreen();
        } else {
            return const AuthScreen();
        }
    },
),
```

Comment: I don't know if I was clear on my need, but I need to include an asynchronous check before returning my `HomeScreen`, and the code snippet you sent is basically what I already said I use.

Comment: cool. u can try one thing, in initState(){ final currentUserId = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser!.uid;  if (currentUserId  ==null){} else{}  }

Comment: But this only will check if there's an user logged in. I want to know if this is the first login of the user. I will do it checking if a document in Firebase Firestore with user ID already exists (and create it if not), and this check is asynchronous.